# Redirecting a domain to Amazon EC2 while serving images from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

To learn AWS I am creating a small image viewing application in node and I am now at the point where whenever I upload images to my application they are persisted in S3. I want these images to be accessible from my own domain as links, but I also want my own domain to redirect to the EC2 instance that runs the app.

In short I want `www.mydomain.com` to point to the EC2 instance and `www.mydomain.com/images/imagename.png` to point to S3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to delegate `images.mydomain.com` to your S3 account with a CNAME record in your DNS that points

`images.mydomain.com` to  `s3.amazonaws.com`

You can then make your links point to:

`images.mydomain.com/your_bucket_name/imagename.png`

to serve them from S3.

Comment: OP doesn't say anything about `images.mydomain.com`, where did you get this name?

Comment: Given that there was no way to do what the OP wanted I was suggesting an alternative. The specific subdomain names are examples and are not important.

Answer (score 0):

Its generally better to serve it directly from S3, or preferably Cloudfront. You could proxy it through your own domain, but it would have to pass through or be redirect by the web server to S3.

Comment: Ok, but won't that mean that links to images will be to `www.my-s3-address.com/image.png` and not to `www.mydomain.com/image.png`? And could you comment on the reason for it being better to serve directly?

Comment: I think what @datasage is getting at is, for the images to appear to be coming directly from your domain in the way you describe, they would have to be pulled from their storage in s3 and served by your web server, or redirected to via a rewrite to your S3 bucket.